# How can i add right collider for a cylinder with hold inside?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a cylinder with a hole inside.
I did the cylinder in blender and exported it to unity.
The problem is that the character walk through the cylinder and i want the character to walk inside but not through.

So i added a capsule collider component to the cylinder.
Now when the character walk in there like a floor since i changed the collider Center on Y to -1.5 and the Radius to 2 and the Height to 4.

The problem is if i will change the collider to be higher then the character will not be able to walk in the hole.

[image: Cylinder with hole]

The collider component on the cyolinder settings in the inspector:

[image: Inspector]

Comment: I would advise to put a `MeshCollider`. You can use the same mesh to define the bounds of the colliders, or you can model a simpler one to use as your Collider.

Comment: Great working..

Answer (score 1):

Either you put a meshcollider , or a mix of sphere and box colliders.